# How to add photo to message on InlineKeyboardButton click in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So I have a bot that uses InlineKeyboard and updates it's message.

The question is pretty simple, is it possible to add image to message on InlineKeyboardButton click? And also can I clear message attachments same way?

My keyboard dispatcher method:

```py
async def keyboard_dispatcher(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    user = update.effective_user

    try:
        button_data = keyboard_callback_schema.loads(query.data)
    except ValidationError as e:
        logging.error(
            f"Validation error ocurred while processing keyboard callback data by user {user.username}, seems like it's wrong callback!",
            exc_info=True,
        )
        await handle_invalid_button(update, context, is_exception=True)
        return

    try:
        await state_methods[button_data["state"]](update, context, data=button_data['data'])
    except KeyError:
        await handle_invalid_button(update, context, is_exception=True)
        return
    except Exception as e:
        await handle_invalid_button(update, context, is_exception=True)
        return

def add_handlers(application: Application):
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("menu", menu))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_invalid_button, pattern=InvalidCallbackData))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(keyboard_dispatcher))
```

Here's one of my dispatched method for one of keyboard's button, that i want to append with image upload:

```py
async def product_view(
    update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE, data: dict[str, any]
):
    """Product view"""
    query = update.callback_query

    product_slug = data["product"]

    product = await api.get.product(product_slug)

    text = "product description"

    

    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="add to cart",
                callback_data=generate_button_callback_data(
                    MenuStates.EMPTY_ACTION,
                )
            )
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="back to categories",
                callback_data=generate_button_callback_data(
                    state=MenuStates.CATEGORIES_SELECT
                )
            )
        ]
    ]

    await query.edit_message_text(
        text=text,
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard),
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )
```

Comment: Yes thats possible, please [edit] your question to show your code.

Comment: @0stone0 added code, you can check it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media messages can not be edited to be text-only messages or vice versa. The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) does not provide any methods for that. Note that this is independent of the python library that you're using (you tagged `python-telegram-bot`), but is a restriction of Telegram itself.

Comment: It seems like it is. So i just added deletion of current message, then i send photo, remembering it's message id, sending another message with keyboard and added to its buttons callback_data's this photo message id. Then i added check for this message in my keyboard dispatcher and deleting message with photo by this id.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add to text message some media by editing telegram method, but in this situation, you should just delete previous message and send new with photo or video.

On the other hand, if you sent a message with a picture, you can use the "editMessageMedia" method to remove the text from the previous messages, but not the picture. Method you can find [here](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1edit_message_media.html)